# Rendering sequence of PNG for later animation - Render output does not show progress very well

Tags: rendering

I have an animation for which I am rendering thousands of PNGs to later be combined by the VSE.  When I start the render animation for the PNGs the Render output window is mostly gray and occasionally flashes an image super fast before if moves to the next PNG (Occasionally a rendered image will stick in the render view but it does NOT list the frame number).

That gives me some idea of where in the sequence my render is, but I have to pay close attention and mostly I miss the frame number it's on.  If I delete all of the previously rendered files I can see which files are being produced on the filesystem so that kind of works, but if I am over-writing files I can't tell.

Is there some way to configure blender render view (like a 1 sec pause between renders for the result to show) or watch the console output to keep track of my sequence generation?

Like I say, more of an irritation than a problem but I would not be surprised if someone has a solution :-)

Comment: I don't think I understand the question completely. If blender is rendering faulty frames but most of the animation is OK, just render the whole thing. In the OS identify the corrupt frames and delete them. Then just re-render and make sure that the overwrite option is disabled. Blender will just render the missing frames without over writing the good ones.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear.  The frames are not faulty.  I am just rendering lots of frames very quickly in rapid succession (to later be put into a video).  The render output window does not show each frame as it renders so I cannot visually track the progress of the multi frame render job